# SASS ERROR : Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties

Tags: css, error-handling, sass

Error:
    @import "./styles/mixins";
    ^
          Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.

My scss file is as simple as that :

```
@import "./styles/mixins";

// There shouldn't be anything else
// Set my variables


@import "styles/variables";

@import "styles/core-style";

@include font-importer("Raleway Regular",'normal',400,"./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf");
@include font-importer("Raleway Bold",'normal',700,"./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Bold.ttf");
@include font-importer("Raleway Light",'normal',300,"./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Light.ttf");
@include font-importer("Raleway Medium",'normal',500,"./assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
```

What does it mean ? I don't understand Sass error. I don't understand where to look at. What do I have to do ?

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: have you tried removing "./" so it becomes `@import "styles/mixins"`

Comment: what is the content of your `mixin` file?

Comment: there are @mixin-s only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What does your `font-importer` return?

**Error explanation:**

> Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes,
>   or other properties.

That means that you call you mixin outside css selector.
For example this code will produce the same error:

```
@mixin color() {
  color: red;
}

@include color(); // call mixin without css selector
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, try adding an underscore before the filename. This will ensure that its not compiled on its own, but only at the main.scss file in one go.

`@import "./styles/_mixins";`

See if that works.

Comment: Nope same same!